# R Y-axis with two main labels

Tags: r, plot

I want to make a scatter plot in R where Y-values are in [-3,-2,-1,1,2,3].
I want to change the Y-axis labels to reflect the binary nature of my data (all positive values are of category A and all negative value of category B), and the numbers themselves specify the subcategories (X,Y,Z for when abs(Y) = 1,2,3).

How can I plot this?

What I want is a Y-axis from -3 to +3 with a main label of "A" when Y>0 and "B" when Y<0 and the normal ticks for the subcategories. Normally I would use Ylab for this, but this only allows ONE main label which is centered, but I want two: each centered at the positive/negative axis.

This is my code so far:

```
X = c(1.5,2.3,2.5,2.1,0.2)
Y = c(1,-3,2,-2,1)

plot(x = X,y=Y,ylab = "Categories",axes=F,ylim = c(-3,3))
axis(2, at=-3:3, labels=c("x","y","z","","x","y","z"))
abline(v = seq(min(X), max(X), 0.2), h = seq(-3,3,1), col = "lightgray", lty = 3)
abline(h=0)
box()
```

which looks like this:
[image]
So I want "A" to be stated on the left side above the X-axis and "B" on the left side below the X-axis.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Can you put a numerical (reproducible) example?

Comment: I added an example; I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mtext()` e.g.:

```
mtext('A', side=2, line=2, at=2)
mtext('B', side=2, line=2, at=-2)
```

and add `las=2` if you want it horizontally.